# Ubuntu 10.04 - install-info error during update

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, package-management

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 beta 1. When I try to update & upgrade I get the following error:

```
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-5ubuntu1) ...
/etc/environment: line 4: LC-ALL=en_US.UTF-8: command not found
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: *install-info* is a particular package; looks like it's currently broken.  you might try downloading it [from here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/install-info) and installing it by hand with `dpkg -i /path/to/package-file.deb` .. if the new one keeps crashing, send a bug report to the Ubuntu folks at http://launchpad.net/

Comment: ironically, i need to have install-info installed to install other packages. but thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out.
In /etc/environment file I had to change this:

```
LC-ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

to this:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I only needed to edit `/etc/environment`

There was a space in the line like this:

```
LC_ALL="en_US. UTF-8"
```

After fixing to the following and saving, it solved the problem:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try out this

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in addition to the above error I get the following:

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove a line from /etc/environment about my jvm, the folder it was pointing to no longer existed. That might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem for 5 days straight. I had to configure NTP server on my machine and it was not possible without this small change that changed the world for me. Even the updates on my machine were not happening due to this.

This is what I did: I changed the first line of `/etc/environment` from:

```
VTYSH_PAGER = more
```

to:

```
VTYSH_PAGER=more
```

And it started working. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and my solution was to delete a quote-sign in /etc/default/locale from this LC_TIME=""en_US.UTF-8" to this LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Really? You had an error message that referred to `/etc/environment` and `LC-ALL` (“I had the same problem”) and fixed it by editing a line in `/etc/default/locale` that sets `LC_TIME`? Really? You have a working system with a line that has ***one*** (unmatched) quote character?  Really?